# Can I deploy different versions of the same war on different paths?

Tags: tomcat

I'd like to deploy multiple versions of a `.war` on the same Tomcat, on different paths. For example, I'd like `old.war` to serve requests on `/`, and then `new.war` to serve requests under `/new/`.

The `war`s will contain different versions of the same code, so mostly the same packages/classes. This also means they will serve the same endpoints, but naturally with different prefixes (eg, when a request comes for `/someendpoint`, it should be served by `old.war`, and when another comes for `/new/someendpoint`, it should be served by `new.war`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its definitely possible. The only thing to take care about is that no two names of war should be equal.

A good strategy would be use a naming convention to your war. Say eg: project_0_0_1.war and the next one as project_0_0_2.war and so on. You would be then able to deploy different version and yet use all of them

Comment: That's what I'm worried about. The packages and the classes will be the same. Will that not be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes. Name them ROOT.war and new.war.

It gets complicated when using ROOT.war since all url references contain empty context

**someserver/someendpoint**

but new.war will have "new" in all of the paths

**someserver/new/someendpoint**

My approach was to always use relative url references with the application or to set a application scoped variable with the server for context name and then use

```
servletContext.setAttribute("cp", contextPath);
```

**${cp}/someendpoint** in generated urls.

It is easier if you don't use ROOT.war but instead use old.war and new.war.